# Unable to create database table in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I am trying to create a database in Laravel. I am following a tutorial online: http://daylerees.com/codebright/schema. This is my database config and my route file.

app/config/database.php

```
'my_candidatedb' => array(
                'driver'   => 'mysql',
                'host'     => 'localhost',
                'database' => 'test',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => '',
                'prefix'   => '',
                'port'     => '3306',
                'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
                'charset' => 'utf8'
```

app/route.php

```
Route::get('table', function()
{
    try 
    {
        schema::create('candidate', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('candidate_id');
            $table->string('first_name', 32);
            $table->string('last_name', 32);
            $table->string('email', 320);
        });
    } 

    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        return 'Error ' . '<p>'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    }       
});
```

When I hit the URI/table, I do not get any error message except "Whoops, looks like something went wrong.". It would be great if anyone can tell me what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is using php artisan to create a migration, then building your schema.

In terminal from the root of your project, type:

`php artisan migrate:make create_candidate_table`

then navigate to app/database/migrations and you'll see the generated file. Add your schema in the up() method and in the down method drop your schema using:

`Schema::drop('candidate');`

Back in terminal run `php artisan migrate` and the table should generate.

**Migration:**

```
public function up() {

    Schema::create('candidate', function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('candidate_id');
        $table->string('first_name', 32);
        $table->string('last_name', 32);
        $table->string('email', 320);
    });

}

public function down() {

    Schema::drop('candidate');

}
```

This is the recommended and safest (and easiest) way to generate tables.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it so clearly. It works after the migration. Not sure why it's not explained in the book.

Answer (score -1):

Change localhost to IP

'host'     => 'localhost', 
to 
'host'     => '127.0.0.1',

Had the same issue and that solved it